# Understanding C# class behavior in recursive programming

Tags: c#

There is a ListGenerator that accepts an array of int and turns it into a recursive object.

```
public class ListNode
{
    public int val;
    public ListNode next;
    public ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
    public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null)
    {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

public static ListNode GenerateList(int[] nums)
{
    if (nums == null || nums.Length == 0) { return null; }

    var i = 0;
    var first = new ListNode(nums[i]);
    var current = first;

    while (++i < nums.Length)
    {
        current.next = new ListNode(nums[i]);
        current = current.next;
    }

    return first;
}
```

I know that classes in C# are reference type so after executing this line of code `current.next = new ListNode(nums[i]);` the value of `first` variable will change same as `current` and everything is good.

But after `current = current.next;` the value of `first` and `current` are not same. Actually, the `next` property has a value in the `first` but it is null in the `current`.
I don't understand why that is. In my view, `first` must be the same as `current` but it is not.

Comment: _why_ would you think first changing? first never gets reassigned.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I tried it, and it definitely changed. It's part of the leetcode code test. you can see it here: https://github.com/BigEggStudy/LeetCode-CS/blob/22a8a02f7b346e4192beedc3f5cfb375d66467fb/LeetCode.Test/TestHelper.cs#L7

Answer (score 4):

With `var current = first;` you copy the *reference* in `first` to `current`. At that point they refer to the same object. Any change in `current.next` is visible in `first.next`.

Later you reassign `current`, so now that is pointing to something other that `first`. The reference in `first` in not affected.